# How to make a bootable usb from commandline?

Tags: linux-mint, usb, dd, bootable

The question is common, but I am not able to solve it with the explanations I found here.

**Situation:**

- 4GB usb stick
- Manjaro operaing system
- iso image file of linux mint

First, I did:

```
lsblk # and got /dev/sdb for my usb stick
      # I left it unmounted
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb # filled it up with zeros
fdisk # Here, I created a DOS partition table and 1 partition 
      # containing the boot flag
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb # made the fat filesystem on the usb stick

dd if=linuxmint-18-xfce-64bit.iso.part of=/dev/sdb bs=4M 
# Now, I copied the ismoimage onto the usb stick
echo $? # I checked, if dd finished without error, the exit status was 0
mount /dev/sdb /mnt  #I mounted the usb stick and listed its content
# the content surprised me, it was not the isoimage-file but this:
```

boot
casper
dists
EFI
isolinux
MD5SUMS
pool
preseed
README.diskdefines

Then, I set the boot order in uefi as usb stick first, 
but it did not worked, I only saw my GRUB loader window 
and started into Manjaro like always.

Comment: `linuxmint-18-xfce-64bit.iso.part` looks like a partially downloaded (broken) file. grub can boot from any iso: http://git.marmotte.net/git/glim/tree/grub2 , so you haven't to change the boot order.

Comment: If someone has a bad internet connection, it is better to download the iso with:  wget <address> , if the connection breaks, one can resume the download with wget -c <address>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should verify the `.iso` image : [Steps to verify an ISO image](https://linuxmint.com/verify.php)

The available linux image come wiht the `.iso` extension and not `.iso.part`

Before unplugging your USB it is recommanded to run `sync`

There is an example:

```
dd if=linuxmint-18-xfce-64bit.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress oflag=sync
```

[**Edit**](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb)

> The `sync`is to make sure that all the writes are flushed out before the command returns.
>
> `if` is input file (or device), `of` is output file (or device)
>
> `bs=4M` tells `dd` to read/write in 4 megabyte chunks for better performance; the default is 512 bytes, which will be much slower
>
> `progress` : shows periodic transfer  statistics.

[manpages : `dd`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/coreutils/dd.1.en.html)

Comment: what is sync doing?

Comment: great explanation, I only do not get what "sync" is doing technically. What is the meaning of "all the writes are flushed out before the command returns" ....has it sth. to do with the swap-partition or cache?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know your USB device block file (such as `/dev/sdb`) and if you want to make sure you're not writing over one of your sata system drives, you can use the more secure [`bootiso utility`](https://github.com/jsamr/bootiso).

You can give your USB device name explicitly (**will fail if it is not connected through USB**):

```
bootiso -d /dev/sdb linuxmint-18-xfce-64bit.iso
```

Or let him find it for you:

```
bootiso linuxmint-18-xfce-64bit.iso
```

See it in action:

[image]